# rc.local runs .sh file in wrong directory

Tags: startup, command-line, directory

In `rc.local` I added a line for my shell file I want to run on boot:

```
/direc/tory/<fileName>.sh
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!bin/sh
wget "http://somesite.org/someJava.jar" -O /direc/tory/someJavaFile.jar
java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx512M -jar /direc/tory/someJavaFile.jar
```

and I would assume it would run and load in the `/direc/tory/` folder but it keeps running in `/` and it saves all its files in there as well.

What do I have to do to force it to run in the `/direc/tory/` folder?

Comment: Why would you assume that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script doesn't contain any command to set the current directory, so it runs in the same directory as the process that invoked it. When it's executed from `rc.local`, which is executed from `init`, the current directory is the root directory `/`.

Add `cd /direc/tory/` to your script. By the way, note that it's `#!/bin/sh` (`#!bin/sh` happens to work here only because you're executing your script from the root directory; it's a very bad idea to rely on this.)

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /direc/tory
wget "http://somesite.org/someJava.jar" -O someJavaFile.jar
java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx512M -jar someJavaFile.jar
```

I also added `set -e` in the script. This makes it stop if one of the commands fails. For example, if `wget` cannot download the jar, then `java` isn't executed.

Comment: are you saying that I should not be using the #!bin/sh in my shell script?

Comment: @Fate Yes, always use `#!/bin/sh` (or `#!/usr/bin/perl` or `#!/direc/tory/myinterpreter` or whatever is appropriate), with a full path.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
wget "http://somesite.org/someJava.jar" -O /direc/tory/someJavaFile.jar
cd /direc/tory
java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx512M -jar /direc/tory/someJavaFile.jar
```

Comment: Thank you Gilles.  I stumbled around trying to figure the formatting out, but nothing looked right.